# como solucionar Deprecated mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql

Alguien me podria ayudar con este script porfavor? resulta que desde hace algun tiempo me salta este error

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\wamp\www\001\proyecto\engine\news.php on line 30

yo utilizo mucho este codigo para algunos proyectos de caracter basico. Me vendria bien algo de ayuda para solucionar esto.

### Archivo "nuevos.php"

```
include_once($path . 'settings.php');

$dbcon = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_passwd); mysql_select_db($db_name);

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT variable,value FROM ' . $db_prefix . 'settings');

    $Settings = array(); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $Settings[$row['0']] = $row['1']; 
    }
```

### Archivo "auth.php"

```
session_start(); $dbQueries = 0;

include_once('settings.php'); error_reporting(0);

$dbcon = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_passwd); checkCon($dbcon);

$dbcon = mysql_select_db($db_name); checkCon($dbcon);

$dbcon = mysql_query('SELECT variable,value FROM ' . $db_prefix . 'settings'); $dbQueries++; checkCon($dbcon);

function checkCon ($con) { if (!$con) { echo mysql_error(); exit(); } }

error_reporting(0);

$Settings = array(); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbcon)) { $Settings[$row[0]] = $row[1]; }

$auth = false; $in_user = ''; $in_password = '';

if((isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) || (isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))) {
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) { $in_user = $_SESSION['user']; $in_password = $_SESSION['password']; } else if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) { if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $in_user = addslashes($_POST['user']); $in_password = addslashes($_POST['password']); } else { $in_user = $_POST['user']; $in_password = $_POST['password']; } }

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $db_prefix . 'posters WHERE username = \'' . $in_user . '\' AND password = password(\'' . $in_password . '\')'); $dbQueries++;

if(mysql_numrows($result) != 0) { $auth = true; $_SESSION['user'] = $in_user; $_SESSION['password'] = $in_password; } else { $bad_details = true; }

$userDetails = array(); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ $userDetails = $row; }
```

Comment: el problema como ahi mismo lo dice es que esa función de mysql_* ya esta obsoleta y en desudo o bien cambias a mysqli o PDO no hay de otra

Comment: Debes actualizar tu código a `mysqli` o `PDO`. PHP "deprecó" `mysql_***` en la versión 5.5 (2013) y se eliminó en la 7.0 (2015). El soporte de la 5.5 finalizó en 2016 y ya vamos por la 7.3 estable. La buena noticia es que no hay muchas cosas que cambiar en la sintaxis en si, ya que es casi la misma.

Answer (score 3):

Como dice el mensaje:

> ... use mysqli or PDO instead

Tienes que cambiar a mysqli o a PDO.

Aquí te mostraré cómo migrar tu código a mysqli, ya que es lo más parecido a la extensión antigua que tenías.

Recomendaría que tengas un sólo archivo donde te conectes a la base de datos. Cuando necesites conexión incluyes ese archivo y nada más.

#### `conexion.php`

```
include_once($path . 'settings.php');

$dbcon = new mysqli($db_server, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_name);
if ($dbcon->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error: " . $dbcon->connect_error . "\n";
}
```

Dejamos en `conexion.php` la creación de un objeto conexión y lo incluimos donde lo necesitemos.

#### `nuevos.php`

```
include('conexion.php');  //Si no está en la misma carpeta de nuevos.php especificar
$sql="SELECT variable,value FROM $db_prefix.settings";
$result = $dbconn->query($sql);
$Settings = array(); 

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { 
        $Settings[] = $row; 
}

/*$Settings será un arreglo asociativo de resultados*/
/*Probando contenido dentro*/
var_dump($Settings);
```

#### `auth.php`

Podría ayudarte a corregir el código también ahí, pero tiene una lógica tan confusa que es imposible entender lo que intentas hacer ahí...

De todos modos, si entiendes el funcionamiento de `nuevos.php` podrás hacer el resto. Lo importante es aprender a crear la conexión usando la nueva API mysqli.