# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db()

Tags: php, mysql

Aparentemente me sigue dando error debido a que ciertos parámetros en la sintaxis están obsoletos. Intente reestructurar la sintaxis pero me sigue mandando el mismo error. ¿Alguien podría darme una mano?

El error es:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in 649 y 662

El código:

```
<?php
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_list)) {
        if ($row['Database'] == strtolower($dbname)) {
            fatal_error('CONTENT_INSTALLER_ERRORCREATEDB');
        }
    }
    /* Create new database */
    mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE '.$dbname.'');

    $dbcreate = 'done';
}

mysql_select_db($dbname);
mysql_query
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP estás usando? Recuerda que las versiones 5.* han salido de soporte y que en PHP 7.* no existen las funciones `mysql_*`.

Comment: Ver la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967). Es muy probable que tu versión de PHP ya no soporte la API `mysql_*`
  y tengas que migrar a `mysqli` o a `PDO`. De hecho [tu pregunta de ayer indicaba eso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233767/29967) y te di una respuesta con unas pautas mínimas para migrar el código. ¿No has intentando nada al respecto?

Comment: Te confirmamos que en PHP 7.* esas funciones no existen (llevan muuuchos años avisando que dejarían de estar disponibles en versiones futuras de PHP con mensajes de advertencia indicando **The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future**). Debes migrar tu código a [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli.examples-basic) o bien [`PDO/mysql`](http://php.net/pdo.connections).

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con [este comentario tuyo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234143/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-select-db#comment435209_234162) ... es de muy mal gusto. [Ayer escribí una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233821/29967) a otra pregunta tuya donde te expliqué algunos puntos básicos sobre la forma de migrar el código. Aquí nadie te ha dicho *`jód**e`* migrando tu código. En aquella respuesta hay un ejemplo claro de un `while`, solo tendrías que cambiar el método. Y el Manual de PHP tiene explicaciones claras al respecto. Aquí se intenta ayudar.

Comment: y es otro Jodete de manera educada... Gracias Señor SACERDOTE jeje

Comment: sigo explicando que el error es en otro archivo, que intentado cambiar el parametro, la sintaxis y que sigo aqui por la misma ayuda

Comment: sigue el mismo error, ya cambie el parametro y nada...  ya no se que debo cambiar

Comment: ¿Ves todas las funciones que empiezan así *`mysql_`*? Ninguna de ellas te va a funcionar. Así que donde quiera que vas código así debes hacerte a la idea de que tienes que migrarlo. Y como expliqué en la otra pregunta, la forma de conectarte a la base de datos tiene que cambiar. De hecho te sugerí que conectes en un solo sitio y luego incluyas el archivo de la conexión, así todo será más fácil. ¿Estamos de acuerdo en ese punto?

Comment: Por otra parte, el código que muestras en esta pregunta tiene una lógica que no se entiende y que quizá es hasta desfasada. Si quieres que te ayudemos debes explicar la lógica del código, por ejemplo, ¿qué sentido tiene esto: `mysql_select_db($dbname);`? ¿qué es lo que hace el código globalmente? Sin entender eso es imposible meterse en una migración y hacerla que funcione. Además hay nuevas técnicas y quizá sea el momento de optimizarlo todo. Lo bueno sería que llegues a comprender la forma correcta en que funciona la nueva API y podrás hacer un trabajo de optimización interesante.

Comment: Absolutamente mi estimado. completamente de acuerdo, pido disculpas si mi comentario o mis comentarios no fueron de manera esperada, lo cierto es que unos leñadores andan con un bullicio talando arboles sin temor alguno cosa que me molesta drasticamente

Comment: a ver mi estimado te explico que hace el codido, ese codigo es un pequeño installer lo cual hace una llamada a detectar listas de DB para crear una BD nueva con usuario y esas cosas... algo asi como el installer del wordpress pero mas basico

Comment: No se puede programar con ruido, se necesita concentración, sobre todo en puntos delicados del programa, como parece ser el caso. Intenta explicar la lógica del código, olvídate de la migración, eso es lo de menos: **hay que entender la lógica de un código para migrarlo**. Si no sabes cómo migrar y quieres que alguien te ayude a hacerlo, debes explicarle a esa persona la lógica del programa. Para ello conviene que edites la pregunta, no que expliques en comentarios que son menos visibles y limitados en el espacio.

Comment: completamente de acuerdo. dicho esto lo que hace el codigo es simple. es un installer que trata de conectar al SQL para crear una base de datos nueva. El instaler pide, host, usuario, clave ynombre de la base de datos que se va a crear. justo en esa linea tira el error. al tratar de conectar a la BD

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a retomar la cuestión de la migración.

### 1. La conexión cambia

[Ya está explicado en otra parte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233821/29967). Y también se indicaba que crearas la conexión en un archivo a aparte, de modo que sólo incluyas ese archivo cuando necesites conectarte.

### 2. Migrar las partes del código

- a) Vamos a aprovechar para optimizar, descartando maneras de hacer antiguas u obsoletas
- b) Vamos a usar el estilo orientado a objetos, porque es más corto, más claro y más moderno que el estilo procedural. O sea, la llamada a funciones no se hará así: `mysqli_funcion_cualquiera_a_veces_larguisma($conexion,$parametros)`, sino que se hará así: `$objeto->metodo($parametros)`.

### 3. Migración para este caso

Lo primero que hay que señalar es que no existe una función del tipo `mysql_list_dbs()` en la nueva API `mysqli`.  Tampoco hace falta, porque se puede obtener una lista de las bases de datos lanzando una consulta como esta: `SHOW DATABASES` ... no hay más misterio en ese punto.

Dando por supuesto que ya sabes conectar al nuevo estilo (te lo expliqué en otra pregunta), procedemos a migrar **este código**:

```
<?php 

    /*
        Vamos a asumir que el objeto de conexión se llama $dbcon (respuesta anterior)
        y que creaste un archivo llamado conexjon.php que conecta de forma correcta
        usando la nueva API mysqli.
        Incluimos ese archivo y la conexión estará en el contexto
    */
    include ('conexion.php');
    if( !$dbcon ) {
        
        echo "No hay conexión disponsible";
        
    } else {
        /*
            Consulta para listar las bases de datos
        */
        $sql="SHOW DATABASES";
        $rs=$dbcon->query($sql);
    
        if ( $rs->num_rows === 0 ) {
            
            echo "No se encontraron bases de datos... vamos a crear una";
            /*
                OJO: aquí conviene usar consultas preparadas
                para evitar ataques de inyección SQL
            */
            $sqlCreate="CREATE DATABASE '$dbname'";
            $rsCreate=$dbcon->query($sqlCreate);
            $msg= ( $rsCreate ) ? "DB $dbname creada con éxito" : "Error: ".$dbcon->error;
            echo $msg;
            
        } else {
            
            while ( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
                if ($row['Database'] == strtolower($dbname)) {
                    fatal_error('CONTENT_INSTALLER_ERRORCREATEDB');
                }            
            }            
        }
    }

?>
```

Esto debería funcionar. Si hay problemas lo dices en comentarios.

*That's all folks!*

Comment: ¡ATENCIÓN!, he arreglado esta línea, cuya forma correcta es: `$msg= ( $rsCreate ) ? "DB $dbname creada con éxito" : "Error: ".$dbcon->error;`, en la primera versión de la respuesta era errónea.